# Find and check if negative write

Tags: find, goto

i'm creating a batch file and just a little thing i want to know:

my (WINDOWS) batch file needs to search 'hello' in a text file.

If it is there, it should use the GOTO command to somewhere else in the batch file.

If it isn't there, it should write 'hello' on a new line.

How can you do that?

I know that you can use FIND and ERRORLEVEL, but i don't know how.

Comment: What kind of batch file - for Windows, or for bash or for what?

Comment: bash doesn't have a GOTO

Comment: Bash is not have batch files, it is a shell script. And it is a full blown scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows batchfiles, check if you can use helpers like the [Unxtools](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/). They are adding a lot of functionality.
Then you can use a grep and check the errorlevel (return value) ...

**EDIT:**
Here is some code to give you an idea:

```
find /i /c "hello" file.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto :found
echo hello
```

Comment: i dont think you need unxtools, i think you can use the FIND command, but i'm not sure. And please give the code.

Comment: You don't need them - but I recommend to have a look at them!

Comment: what would if %errorlevel%... do? will it GOTO if it IS Found?

Comment: open a console and enter the find command - the very next line write "echo %errorlevel%" ... you can see that it returns 0 or 1, depending on what is found in your file ... it should do what you want - if hello is found the goto is used, otherwise hello is printed.

Comment: it doesnt. it should have been 'equ 0' because now it goes to :found when it is not found

Comment: does not work on windows 7... Gives me a list of all the folders in the c directory. it says something like: find /i is no medium or so?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most helpful answer... but, does it have to be a batch file? It sounds like Perl might be a better fit for what you are trying to do.

Comment: nah, i think that's not needed. I thought you could use something with FIND and ERRORLEVEL, but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
echo off
find /c "hello" myfile.txt > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto notfound
echo hello
:notfound
```

Comment: no, i dont want to do it like that, if it IS found, than use GOTO.
if its NOT found, than it has to write that to the text file on a new line.

Comment: Come on... he gave you a solution, you can customize it the way you want... I don't think that you can expect other people to write your code. Take a look at http://www.allenware.com/icsw/icsw070.htm for appending text to a file.